# I need my images in my table to follow some height and width rules

Tags: css, html

I am getting images from backend, so I don't know which size they are, but I need them to follow some rules:

1. If the image's *height* is greater than 45px then I need the *width* to be 170px and *height* to maintain the aspect ratio of original image.
2. If image *height* is less or equals 45px then I need the *height* to be 45px and *width* to maintain the aspect ratio of the original image.

Speaking mathematically and slightly coding language:

if image.height > 45px, then make finalImage.width = 170px and finalImage.height follows to the aspect ratio of the original image.

if image.height <= 45px, then make finalImage.height = 45px and make finalImage.width change according to aspect ratio of original image.

I have tried some code but its not changing the width if height <= 45px.

```html
<img class = "modify" src = "URL" />
```

```css
.modify {
  min-height: 45px;
  width: 170px;
  height: auto;
}
```

This code is changing the width according to aspect ratio and not caring about the height, i.e even if height <= 45px; its taking width 170px. But I want the width to change according to the same aspect ratio and height = 45px.

Comment: CSS doesn't support conditional logic. Most elegant solution would likely require some JS. Or implement a separate stylesheet language like Sass.

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't have conditional logic, so you have to solve that using JS:

```css
/* class for images with height > 45px */
img.modify.gt45 {
  width: 170px;
  height: auto;
}

/* class for images with height <= 45px */
img.modify.lte45 {
  height: 45px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { 
  // get all images with "modify" class
  document.querySelectorAll('img.modify').forEach((img) => {
    // set "onload" event handler
    img.onload = function () {
      // add appropriate image class
      this.classList.add( this.height > 45 ? 'gt45' : 'lte45' );
    };
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay. This is not very optimized solution but it will definitely work. I guess your HTML image element looks like this:

```
<img src="source/to/the/path.jpg">
```

First I am going to wrap your image in a div and give a unique id to both the div and the image so that the HTML becomes like this:

```
<div id="image-container">
    <img src="source/to/the/path.jpg" id="image">
</div>
```

Now I can manipulate the image using javascript like this:

```
var img = document.getElementById('image');
img.onload = function() {
    var height = this.height;
    if (height > 45) {
        document.getElementById('image-container').innerHTML = '<img src="source/to/the/path.jpg" height="'+height+'px">'
    } 
    else {
        document.getElementById('image-container').innerHTML = '<img src="source/to/the/path.jpg" height="45px">'
    }
}
```

Comment: It will not work, because `onload` handler will be called only after image loading and long after this `if` check.

Comment: I accidentally misplaced the `if` statement and I guess now it's fixed.